# How to access 2d graphics from inside a keylistener method

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, graphics2d

Hi I am trying to be able to move around a 2d stick figure for a high school game, I have a keylistener and methods but I am not able to use p1.translate to move based on what they press. I attempted to use a loop/if statement to check what button was pressed using a variable(x) and moving based on that but it didint work either. So basically I am trying to access the p1(my 2d graphic stickman) from the methods to move him. I tried the one in the duplicate and their fix was NOT working for me.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;


public class game extends Frame{
    int x = 0;
    //used to call the frame I just created
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new game();
    }

    //creates the frame
    public game(){
        super("2D World"); //output
        setSize(800,400);
        setVisible(true);

        //closes it when we hit X
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {dispose(); System.exit(0);}


        });}
        public void paint(Graphics p1){
            p1.setColor(Color.black);
            p1.drawOval(100, 200, 20, 20);
            p1.drawLine(110, 220, 110, 240);
            p1.drawLine(110, 240, 117, 260);
            p1.drawLine(110, 240, 100, 260);
            p1.drawLine(110, 220, 117, 240);
            p1.drawLine(110, 220, 100, 240);

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            switch(evt.getKeyCode()) {
               case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:  moveLeft();  break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: moveRight(); break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_UP: moveUp(); break;
               case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: moveDown(); break;

            }
         }
      });


    }
    protected void moveUp() {
        x = 1;

    }

    protected void moveRight() {
        x = 2;
    }

    protected void moveLeft() {
        x =3;
    }
    protected void moveDown() {
        x = 4;
    }

    /*class DrawCanvas extends JPanel{
        public void paint(Graphics p1){
            p1.setColor(Color.black);
            p1.drawOval(100, 200, 20, 20);
            p1.drawLine(110, 220, 110, 240);
            p1.drawLine(110, 240, 117, 260);
            p1.drawLine(110, 240, 100, 260);
            p1.drawLine(110, 220, 117, 240);
            p1.drawLine(110, 220, 100, 240);

        }
    }*/
    }
```

Comment: `public class game extends Frame{` A `Frame` is an AWT class while the tags include Swing. A Swing frame is a `JFrame`.

Comment: I am in high school, I thought swing was involved with JPanels aswell. The duplicate did not help me so I still am not sure how to fix my issue.

Comment: *"I am in high school,"* Good for you, but that has no relevance to the question. *"I thought swing was involved with JPanels aswell."* `JPanel` is a Swing component, but all the panel related code seen above is commented out. *"The duplicate did not help me"*  Did you research (as in, read the Java Docs of) all the methods mentioned in the accepted answer? Did you try calling those methods in your code? Don't expect people here to spoon-feed solutions to you. That's not how the site works.

Comment: My point was that I am not adept at coding at all what so ever, don't expect me to be when I literally said in the original post it's for a high school project. You literally marked my post as a duplicate when he did something different than me, it's the same general idea but he ended up not even calling it inside his key listener so it literally had no meaning for me. I read the answers and tried them and none worked nor did they even fit what I was attempting, I don't expect anyone to spoonfeed me, I expect them to give input on what to try. There's a reason I stated what I tried already.